# How to find the location, where an an Emacs Lisp function is bound to a key?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to figure out where <kbd>M-m</kbd> is bound to `back-to-indentation` function. When I issue <kbd>C-h k M-m</kbd> (`describe-key`), I get the following output

> M-m runs the command back-to-indentation, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to M-m.
>
> (back-to-indentation)
>
> Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line.

When I look at `simple.el`, I'm seeing only the definition of function `back-to-indentation`. I searched throughout the file and I didn't see any keybinding done for that function using `define-key`. I'm assuming that it happens elsewhere.

How can I identify the location where the function is bound to <kbd>M-m</kbd> key?

> Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0, NS apple-appkit-1187.34)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have made accidental discovery of useful keystrokes when looking at the lisp files. Whenever I stare using a new module, I look for `define-key` lines in that to see if there are any interesting bindings that I can make use of. `M-m` is a binding that I discovered accidentally. I wanted to see what other useful bindings that are provided in the same class. `C-h b` kind of displays too many bindings under General Bindings category, that makes it difficult to focus on a similar group of bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that's possible in general, but my guess would be that Emacs doesn't remember where the code was that defined a given key.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> will show the current bindings, from which you can establish which keymap you're interested in, and work from there. For most major or minor mode maps, it won't be too difficult to find the code.

Your specific example is a global binding which Emacs configures in `bindings.el`.

Comment: somehow `shift + m` got binded to `Meta` key in my config & it cant type `Mock` now. is there a way find or unbind it?

Comment: Modifier keys can only be assigned at the OS-level, so that must have happened outside of Emacs. Either that, or your description of the problem is unclear. I presume `C-h k` followed by `shift + m` does nothing?

Comment: with `emacs -Q` everything works fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226265/how-to-find-where-a-key-binding-is-defined-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

Adding this at the beginning of my `.emacs` did the trick for me:

```
(let ((old-func (symbol-function 'define-key))
      (bindings-buffer (get-buffer-create "*Bindings*")))
  (defun define-key (keymap key def)
    (with-current-buffer bindings-buffer
      (insert (format "%s -> %s\n" key def))
      (mapbacktrace (lambda (evald func args flags)
                      (insert (format "* %s\n" (cons func args))))))
    (funcall old-func keymap key def)))
```

The idea is that I redefine the `define-key` function (which is used to bind `key` within `keymap` to `def`) to first log its arguments to a buffer `*Bindings*`, together with the stacktrace of where it's being called from. After that it calls the old version of the function.

This creates a closure to store the old value of `define-key`, so it depends of `lexical-bindings` being `t`. In retrospect, I think it would have been possible to use function advising instead; but using a closure felt simpler.

Since I had this at the beginning of my `.emacs`, this recorded all calls to `define-key` during initialization. So I just had to switch to that buffer once initialization finished, find the call where the particular key was bound, and then inspect the backtrace to find the site from which that happened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you add some explanation why this solved your problem?

Comment: Kindly add more details to your answer, explanations on how your code works and how this address the OP's question would be a great help not just for the asker but also for the future researchers.

Comment: Ah, sure, sorry... Just added the explanation to the main body of the answer.

Comment: This jusd yields an error message, nothing more.

Comment: Hi, @PhilippLudwig, can you share the error that you get? I could look into why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Edgar: `global-set-key: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (keymap key def) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer bindings-buffer) (insert (format "%s -> %s
" key def)) (mapbacktrace #'(lambda (evald func args flags) (insert (format "* %s
" (cons func args)))))) (funcall old-func keymap key def)), 4`

Comment: Hum, so I'm using Emacs 27.1, but I see that in the latest EmacsLisp documentation, the `define-key` function takes an optional `remove` argument: 

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Key-Binding.html#index-define_002dkey

I haven't narrowed down what version the extra parameter was added, but you can update my code to handle it, I think something like the following should do it:

`(let (...) (defun define-key (keymap key def &optional remove) ... (funcall old-func keymap key def remove)))`