# how to find where a key binding is defined in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

Somehow `shift + m` is got bound to `Meta` key in emacs. Now I cant type any words that start with `M` like `Mock`. I want to find why it is happening or which package is causing this.

There is [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354894/how-to-find-the-location-where-an-an-emacs-lisp-function-is-bound-to-a-key) regarding this issue but doesn't solve this problem.

I tried `C h k m` which showed `m runs command self-insert-command`

But when when i try `C h k M` it is activating `Meta` key and is waiting for another key to input.

The same is happening with `C h c M`.

Is there any way to find out what is causing this?

**Update:**

1. My emacs config https://github.com/ChillarAnand/.emacs.d
2. The problem is not occuring at OS level. If I start emacs with `emacs -Q` everything works fine.

Comment: Perhaps the `meta-prefix-char` was set to the capital letter M?  If that sounds possible, you could grep your customizations and third-party libraries for that variable.  On my machine, a capital letter M is 77.  You can use `describe-variable` to check the value.

Comment: I guess it's [`(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M up") nil)`](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/.emacs.d/blob/d7b688f3a666cee937eb42ab2ab12df96a00fa9c/personal/packages.el#L48), it's binding `M u p` to `nil`. You really want `(kbd "M-<up>")`

Comment: Note that when you press your Meta key (or Ctrl key, or any other modifier), Emacs does *not* then wait for another key like this. Pressing and releasing a modifier key does nothing at all, so "activating Meta key" is a misleading description -- it's neither what is happening, nor something which makes a great of sense (unless calling `event-apply-meta-modifier`, but it's hard to bind something to that by accident).

Comment: I'm still searching for the answer to this title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the [code](https://github.com/ChillarAnand/.emacs.d/blob/d7b688f3a666cee937eb42ab2ab12df96a00fa9c/personal/packages.el#L48)

```
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M up") nil)
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M down") nil)))
```

This doesn't bind `shift m` as `Meta` but rather binds the key sequences `M u p` and `M d o w n` to `nil`. To specify <kbd>Meta</kbd> inside `kbd` use `M-{the key}`, to specify <kbd>up</kbd> use `<up>`, for the code in question:

```
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M-<up>") nil)
(define-key smartparens-mode-map (kbd "M-<down>") nil)))
```

Comment: That's a solution to your problem, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Atemu s/your/OP's/, but yes that's true. There isn't really a good answer to the question, Emacs doesn't record that info.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this at the beginning of my .emacs did the trick for me:

```
(let ((old-func (symbol-function 'define-key))
      (bindings-buffer (get-buffer-create "*Bindings*")))
  (defun define-key (keymap key def)
    (with-current-buffer bindings-buffer
      (insert (format "%s -> %s\n" key def))
      (mapbacktrace (lambda (evald func args flags)
                      (insert (format "* %s\n" (cons func args))))))
    (funcall old-func keymap key def)))
```

Comment: See the explanation of how it works in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354894/how-to-find-the-location-where-an-an-emacs-lisp-function-is-bound-to-a-key/72253450

Comment: This just yields an error message.

Comment: See once more the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354894/how-to-find-the-location-where-an-an-emacs-lisp-function-is-bound-to-a-key/72253450 for a potential work-around.